# How to add From & To in reply all in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I am using thunderbird as my Email Client. When i click reply all in my Email It doesn't shows From ID, To ID, CC, Date & Time. I just want to enable this From To Cc Date & Time in reply all. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't encounter any date in my thunderbird, or any cc, it is only from and a to, and after first to some lines if you click on that you can write another email address.
So if you don't have even a from that is a bug, uninstall and reinstall is my solution.